# Company administrator is shown as ID in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

By default every site collection has the Company Administrator group assigned as the primary administrator, that's clear.

When I have a look at the permissions on office.com, then I can see the group name. But when I look them up in Sharepoint, I just see a strange ID like this: `c:0-.f|rolemanager|s-1-5-21-1690953445-677975096-35`.

What causes this? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was just a confusing displayed name of the Company Administrator user/group.

I fixed this issue by removing this group from every other groups and as the site collection administrator and deleted the user from the user and groups page of the site settings. The only important connection is the assignment as the site collection administrator. You can't delete the user if this connection is still there.

After that you just need to reassign this user to everything it was connected to. Now the correct name is displayed instead of the SID.